# Loading Video Files via Ajax and Views

Tags: views

I am looking for a way to implement a gallery style selection for a content type containing multiple videos.  I am using Drupal 7.

I have a content type called roles which has a title, banner image, description, videos and video thumbnails.

The videos and video thumbnails are file fields which can accept multiple files (the idea being that you can upload the videos then the thumbnail for each video in the same sequence).

At the moment to display videos on the site I am using mediaelement - however for this page layout I need to be able to show the video thumbnails then let the user select and have it load the video via an ajax call.

I have tried using views filters exposed to the user based on the videos file id, however this seems to break the videos.

Is there another way to accomplish this in views? Or is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly changed the way I handled this after following the excellent tutorial 
[Creating a Simple AJAX Interface with Views](http://mrkadin.com/blog/node/70)

All is up and working now.

Comment: Would you be able to post a link to your site / solution? Am looking to do the same thing and would like to see the finished result. Many thanks, PW